# Editing a C++ program after I click "run"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am just learning the basics of programming using C++. After I write my program on VS code, it wont let me go back and edit certain things. The curser becomes a thick block and it wont let me type. How/why is this happening? The only way I can get it to stop is to click on my keyboard a bunch of times and for some reason that allows me to do it, but I end up deleting or typing a bunch of stuff. Is there a way to fix this?

When I try to input data it says I can't because it says it "cannot edit in read-only editor". Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: It could be what happens if the debugger mode is engaged where changing the source then would potentially mess up the line numbers. Keep in mind Visual Studio Community or XCode are often a lot more friendly for newer developers, so consider those if it's an option.

Comment: You can change the settings, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879495/14291507

Comment: You can't edit the code while the program is running. (With few exceptions.)

Comment: if you edit the code then the project has to be recompiled, and that's very tricky while debugging. Only a few compilers/debuggers support this like MSVC

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It happens also when I just open a folder or a file when starting the program. I am not able to go change anything. I've downloaded XCode so I'll see if I can get the hang of that instead.

Comment: I fixed the issue! I had to disable my VIM and it allowed me to edit again.