# C++ output window not working as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

ok so I just started learning today, This simple code works as expected when I run it in the integrated terminal but not in the output window, I'm not able to type in the numbers, any suggestions on how to solve the issue ?
[Executed in output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x64bl.png)

[Executed in terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hraj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cin or cout in vscode on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307083/unable-to-cin-or-cout-in-vscode-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this Question: [Cannot edit in read-only editor VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856374/cannot-edit-in-read-only-editor-vs-code). The VS Code Output window is read-only. So you cannot input any values there. And as your code requires input, it will only work in a terminal (as you can input values there).

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to solve my question, this definitely avoided a lot of confusion.