# ftp-kr - Cannot edit in read-only editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, vscode-extensions

I cannot figure out how to use the [ftp-kr extension](https://github.com/karikera/ftp-kr) for VS Code properly. I have read and re-read the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/karikera/ftp-kr/wiki) and the [README documentation](https://github.com/karikera/ftp-kr/blob/master/README.md) and cannot find any other help for my issue. I posted this question to the project Issues on GitHub but have yet to receive a response.

**ftp-kr** is just a simple extension for editing files via FTP that are located on a remote server. Many other users seem to be using the extension with no issue.

I installed the extension, and then I successfully edited the connection settings (in `ftp-kr.json`) and successfully made a connection to the remote server I am trying to edit files on.

I opened the **FTP-KR: EXPLORER** pane to look at all of the files on the server, but if I double-click any of the files to open them and then try to edit them, I am unable to type and just get a warning in VS Code that says "**Cannot edit in read-only editor**".
I have tried right-clicking on files and clicking the "Download This" button, thinking that maybe I need to download a local copy of the files to edit before uploading the changes. However, whenever I click the "Download This" option on any file in the ftp-kr Explorer, it just gives me an error message that says "**[file_name] is not in remotePath**".
[image: not in remote path error]

I tried running the `>ftp-kr: Download All` command, but it just spits out a notice that says "Nothing to DO".
[image: Nothing to DO]

**How do I edit files located on the remote server and save those changes to the server?**

---

P.S. I have tried the solutions found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856374/cannot-edit-in-read-only-editor-vs-code) but unfortunately none of them seem to work. Particularly, "[code-runner: Run in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879495/5484302)" is not in my settings and "[Edit in Local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805119/5484302)" is not a context menu item that appears in my editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of months, I finally have a solution to this thanks to [the developer eventually responding on GitHub](https://github.com/karikera/ftp-kr/issues/156). There are a few things going on here.

1. Any file that a user wishes to modify must be downloaded as a local copy on the user's machine first and then that copy can be uploaded to the webserver via FTP.
2. ftp-kr cannot auto-download individual files. (Either when they are double-clicked on or through any other method.) It can only download entire directories, and those directories can be changed by using the `localPath` and `ignore` options in the configuration file, then stopping and restarting the ftp connection.

[image: screenshot of the ftp-kr settings]

3. The "Download This" context menu option that appears is a piece of non-implemented code. It will not do anything.

[image: The Download This context menu option]

4. `>ftp-kr: Download All` is the preferred way (by the developer's intent) to download the remote files onto the user's computer. The fact that it was returning an error before was a bug which [has now been fixed](https://github.com/karikera/ftp-kr/issues/156#issuecomment-1336474236).
5. Confusingly, the user can *view* the filenames and context of every file on the remote file system using a convenient tree view, you just cannot simply download any of those files individually.

In all, this plugin does not provide the functionality that I hoped it would have. (Namely, being able to easily download, modify, and upload individual files.) So I know how to properly use it, I will just be switching to a different plugin for my purposes.